# How to style jquery append with dynamic class

Tags: jquery, append

I have a function which append a new list item to an unsorted list, and it will add a class of a user input. I thought I could just set all the possible styles in my stylesheet, but I can't.

Also the container for the new item is an appended element for an earlier click.
so what is the right way to achieve this?

My click function to append the new items

```
$('#columns_ok').click(function() {
    var picked_value = $('#number_of_columns').val();

    if((picked_value >= 1) && (picked_value <= 10)) {
        $('.column_container').append('<li class="'+picked_value+'_used"></li>');
        $(this).parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
    }

    else {
        $('.error').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

and my style for the items:

```
.columns_container li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    height: 150px;
}

.1_used {
    width: 86px;
}

.2_used {
    width: 194px;
}

.3_used {
    width: 302px;
}

.4_used {
    width: 410px;
}

.5_used {
    width: 518px;
}

.6_used {
    width: 626px;
}

.7_used {
    width: 734px;
}

.8_used {
    width: 842px;
}

.9_used {
    width: 950px    
}

.10_used {
    width: 1058px;
}
```

Comment: You can't start with numbers as class, the stylesheet wont work. It must start with a letter

Comment: Simple way to achieve this would be to add the css to the newly adding element as it would avoid pre-declaration of css class, which may or may not be used all time.